# Text View does'nt scroll under Toolbar when anchored to app bar layout

Tags: android, material-design, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

So, instead of FAB I want to put a Styled text view to have the same result as to when putting fab to the anchor. The problem is it doesn't work, when scrolling, half of the text view is still visible, even tough collapsing toolbar is hidden.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <!--android:fitsSystemWindows="true"-->

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

   <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/details_price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/layout_padding"
        android:background="@drawable/drawable_details_price_background"
        android:padding="@dimen/layout_padding"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|left|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

How to achieve such a behaviour with a text view instead of FAB?

Answer (score -1):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/details_price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/layout_padding"
        android:background="@drawable/drawable_details_price_background"
        android:padding="@dimen/layout_padding"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|left|end" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: This answer would be more helpful with some explanation